# Hydroxide formation: reaction of group 13 elements with water

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, water, reactivity

I was studying about 13th group elements and I found that in this group Al and Tl react water to form a hydroxide and oxide respectively, but the rest of the elements don't react to form hydroxides.

Can anyone tell me *why* this is the case?

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone tell me why this is the case?

Though the elements reside in same group, they react with water and form different products. This is mainly due to [*inert pair effect*.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inert_pair_effect)

1. **Boron**

$$\ce{2B + 3H2O ->[700-800 C] B2O3 + 3H2}$$

> Boron react with water to produce boron trioxide(III) and hydrogen.
>   This reaction takes place at a temperature of 700-800°C.([source](http://chemiday.com/en/reaction/3-1-0-464))

2. Aluminium

$$\ce{2Al + 6H2O → 2Al(OH)3 + 3H2}$$

3. Gallium

$$\ce{2Ga + 6H2O → 2Ga(OH)3 + 3H2 ~~~~~~(1)}$$

$$\ce{2Ga + 4H2O ->[350 C] 2GaO(OH) + 3H2O~~~~~(2)}$$

> Gallium react with water to produce gallium oxohydroxide and water.
>   This reaction takes place at a temperature near 350°C. ([source](http://chemiday.com/en/reaction/3-1-0-5493))

4. Thallium

$$\ce{2Tl + H2O ->[atm. O2 ~~~50-70 C] 2TlOH}$$

> Thallium react with oxygen and water to produce thallium(I) hydroxide.
>   This reaction takes place at a temperature of 50-70°C. ([source](http://chemiday.com/en/reaction/3-1-0-12479))

Comment: Would you please become more specific?